# How to show a single value when hovering a Multiline glyph in Bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hover, bokeh, multiline

As for now I see Bokeh supports HoverTool for multi_line glyph. 
But the problem is that if I want to display particular value for point - it shows all the list of values instead of it.

Please, see example below:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

df = {'X_value': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 
      'model': ['m1', 'm1', 'm2', 'm2'], 
      'color': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'],
      'Y_value': [[0.50, 0.66, 0.70, 0.67], [0.65, 0.68, 0.71, 0.66], [0.80, 0.79, 0.84, 0.80], [0.80, 0.83, 0.76, 0.64]]}

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(plot_height=400)
p.multi_line(xs='X_value', ys='Y_value', legend="model", color='color',
             line_width=5, line_alpha=0.6, hover_line_alpha=1.0,
             source=source)

p.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=False, line_policy='next', tooltips=[
    ('X_value', '@X_value'),
    ('Y_value', '@Y_value')
]))

show(p)
```

[image]

I know about $x, $y ability, but that shows coordinated under the mouse, and they are changing as you move a mouse, that is not desired behaviour.

It there a way to display exact value for hover point in multi_line glyph?

p.s. creating invisible line is not a solution, as I have more advanced plot with filtering and linked plots and so on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you update to the bokeh version 0.12.16 you can use the new class [**`CustomJSHover`**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.12.16/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.CustomJSHover) like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.tools import CustomJSHover


df = {'X_value': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]], 
      'model': ['m1', 'm1', 'm2', 'm2'], 
      'color': ['red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue'],
      'Y_value': [[0.50, 0.66, 0.70, 0.67], [0.65, 0.68, 0.71, 0.66], [0.80, 0.79, 0.84, 0.80], [0.80, 0.83, 0.76, 0.64]]}

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p = figure(plot_height=400)
p.multi_line(xs='X_value', ys='Y_value', legend="model", color='color',
             line_width=5, line_alpha=0.6, hover_line_alpha=1.0,
             source=source)

x_custom = CustomJSHover(code="""
    return '' + special_vars.data_x
""")

y_custom = CustomJSHover(code="""
    return '' + special_vars.data_y
""")

p.add_tools(
    HoverTool(
        show_arrow=False, 
        line_policy='next',
        tooltips=[
            ('X_value', '@X_value{custom}'),  # or just ('X_value', '$data_x')
            ('Y_value', '@Y_value{custom}')
        ],
        formatters=dict(
            X_value=x_custom,
            Y_value=y_custom
        )
    )
)

show(p)
```

Comment: Cool. Did not know they've updated the lib. Would be awesome if they add data_x and data_y the standard HoverTool. Smth like $data_x and $data_y similar to the rest of vars.

Comment: btw! I've checked =) it is not documented in docs, but $data_x is really available as well. so you can use default HoverTool without js, and write ('value', '$data_x')

Comment: Nice, even better

Comment: Ah! [The docs are already updated](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.CustomJSHover)

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Dmitriy's comment in the above answer as he said data_x and data_y are now exposed so you just need to change your code to:

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=False, line_policy='next', tooltips=[
    ('X_value', '$data_x'),
    ('Y_value', '$data_y')
]))
```

But what's nice about this is you can use the Bokeh formatters. e.g. this is one I used for values on a date time axis e.g:

```
plot.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=
    [
        ('Date',  '$data_x{%F}'),
        ('Level', '$data_y{0,0.000000}'),
        ('Ticket', '@ticket')
    ],
    formatters={
        '$data_x': 'datetime',
    }
))
```