# How to only show hover tooltip only for the line cursor is on, in a bokeh multiline graph?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh, multiline

So I have plotted and shown hover tooltips for various lines as follows:

```
def plotter(results, title):

    results = results.rename(columns = dict(zip(results.columns, [col.strip().replace(' ','_') for col in results.columns])))
    source = ColumnDataSource(results)
    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300)
    
    for color, col in enumerate(results.columns):
        

        glyph = Circle(x='month', y=col,
                 #source=source,
                 size=3, line_color=Turbo256[color*5], fill_color = Turbo256[color*5])
        p.add_glyph(source, glyph)
        p.line(x='month', y = col, source = source, color = Turbo256[color*5], line_width = 1)

    p.title.text = f"Monthly rates trends Based on {title.replace('_',' ').title()} "
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Months'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Rates'

    hover=HoverTool(show_arrow=False, line_policy='next', tooltips = [
        (col.replace('_',' ').title(), f'@{col}') for col in results.columns] )   
    
    p.add_tools(hover)

    show(p)
```

And while this works fine, it shows tooltips for every line whenever I hover a point on graph. I do not want to show all the tooltips though. I only want those tooltips to show on which cursor currently sits. Like if it is on one line only one tooltip regarding that line should show and if it is on some point where two lines are there, it may show tooltips for two and so on. I have been trying to use `CustomJS` but havent figured out a way. Any help regarding this will be highly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been addressed in another Question:
["How to show a single value when hovering a Multiline glyph in Bokeh?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54484782/18206273)

The trick is to use `'$data_x'` and/or `'$data_y'` for bokeh "special fields":

```
p.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=False, 
                      line_policy='next', 
                      tooltips=[('X_value', '$data_x'),
                                ('Y_value', '$data_y')
]))
```